# Variable dependency not working in YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong with variable dependencies between jobs.

I have the following pipeline, taken almost verbatim from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable):

```yaml
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: build

  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar;isOutput=true]zomg"
      name: ProduceVar
    - script: echo $(ProduceVar.MyVar) # Prints out zomg.

  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'], 'zomg') # Fails, B does not get executed.
    variables:
      varFromA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo $(varFromA) # Does not print out the variable, it is not mapped.
```

The condition for job `B` fails with the following information:

```
Started: Yesterday at 16:19
Duration: 15h 33m 54s
Evaluating: eq(dependencies['A']['outputs']['ProduceVar.MyVar'], 'zomg')
Expanded: eq(Null, 'zomg')
Result: False
```

If I remove that check, the variable dependency is not picked up in the last script which tries to output mapped variable.

The output in this case looks like this:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-latest
Agent: Azure Pipelines 10
Started: Yesterday at 16:22
Duration: 5s

Job preparation parameters
Variables:
  varFromA:
    Parsing expression: <dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar']>
    Evaluating: dependencies['A']['outputs']['ProduceVar.MyVar']
    Expanded: Null
    Result: ''
ContinueOnError: False
TimeoutInMinutes: 60
CancelTimeoutInMinutes: 5
Expand:
  MaxConcurrency: 0
  ########## System Pipeline Decorator(s) ##########

  Begin evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
Evaluating: eq('true', variables['system.debugContext'])
Expanded: eq('true', Null)
Result: False
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']
Expanded: Object
Result: True
Evaluating: not(containsValue(job['steps']['*']['task']['id'], '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Expanded: not(containsValue(Object, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Result: True
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']['checkoutOptions']
Result: Object
Evaluating: pair['key']
Result: 'fetchDepth'
Evaluating: pair['value']
Result: '1'
Evaluating: pair['key']
Result: 'lfs'
Evaluating: pair['value']
Result: 'false'
Finished evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
********************************************************************************
Template and static variable resolution complete. Final runtime YAML document:
steps:
- task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
  inputs:
    repository: self
    fetchDepth: 1
    lfs: false


  MaxConcurrency: 0
```

What makes this even more painful for me: I have other pipelines, where this works perfectly fine, even referencing jobs from different stages.

What silly mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a very weird bug in Azure Pipelines.

The problem is the stage name `build` in combination with the Azure DevOps organization/project that I am using.

Removing the stage definition, or renaming the stage to anything other than `build` resolves the issue.

Keeping the stage name `build` and running this in projects from other organizations resolves the issue.

Pray for us all...

Answer (score 1):

I copied your yaml, **without any changes**,it's working fine on my side. But the `Evaluating` is **different** with yours：

[image]

Please follow below items for a check:

1. Is the yaml shared exactly same with your real one?  Do you have stage, deployment job in your real yaml?
2. Which branch do you have the yaml? Make sure you are running on the correct branch.

[image]

3. If the issue persists, please create a new pipeline with same yaml content in a new repo for a check.

Comment: The similar code was not working in my original, more complex, pipeline, so I made the most simple one I could think of to demonstrate this. **The pipeline is brand new, running the code that I posted above.** I have updated my question with the output of variable expansion when I disable the condition. Compared to yours (and another pipeline of mine that is working), in this one I get an additional `Expanded: Null` line.

Comment: The `Expanded: Null` means you have other expression for `varFromA` value and it could be not correct which caused the variable value to `null`.  It's recommended to share more yaml content for troubelshooting.

Comment: I have pasted the whole log now. There is nothing else there related to `varFromA`.

Comment: In the end it was a strange and unfortunate bug which I describe in my answer. Thank you for your answer - it guided me in the right direction among other things.